# Customer's order can't edit from Magento 2.x Backend

Tags: magento2.1.5

I have tried to edit the customer order from Magento Admin panel but when I have been going to submit the order that time Magento Admin panel is showing an error that is "Please enter a customer email." but in there have no email field to write.

Is there anyone Magento 2.x expert to help me out from this issues or if anyone faced that kind of issue in your system please give me a solution.

Please check my screenshot below.

Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: please post full screenshot here of order creating

Answer (score 0):

Well whenever you try to edit an order it clearly shows that it will be a new order instead. And you have to put an customer email because its a new order.
By default it takes the email from the previous order though. Check the image below [image]

### EDIT

The file is `app\code\Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\data.phtml` which is showing the whole page content. And inside that on line no.33 `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_account') ?>` it is responsible for the email part. Which further calls `app\code\Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\form\account.phtml` this file.

Comment: I can't see any email field in there image link: https://ibb.co/hHvqmQ

Comment: Which version is this? Is this a released version or taken pull from git dev branch? Why both of our UI looks different.

Comment: Version Magento 2.1.5

Comment: It should be there. I am using Magento ver. 2.2.0-dev

Comment: Is there have code to show the email field?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58490/discussion-between-shakib-rahman-and-kingshuk-deb).

Comment: I am using a third party theme. I think for that reason that location will be changed. Could you please tell that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in `app\code\Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\create\data.phtml` file

```
<?php
    $customerEmail = '';
    if($block->getCustomerId())
    {
        $customerID = $block->getCustomerId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
        ->load($customerID);
        $customerEmail = $customerObj->getEmail();
    }

    ?>
    <input id="email" name="order[account][email]" data-ui-id="billing-address-fieldset-element-text-order-account-email" value="<?php echo $customerEmail ?>" type="hidden">
```